# SVN error : Failed to add directory 'bin/classes/com'

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, subversive

I'm getting the error in the title of the question:

```
"svn: Failed to add directory 'bin/classes/com'an unversioned directory of the same name already exists"
```

when im trying to "switch" from my current branch to the trunk. It simply wont allow me to switch. This error occured when I updated the Android target on the branch and the Trunk without problems ( updated from 2.2 -> 3.0). But now I keep getting that error!

I'm not sure how to resolve this. Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix this problem by using the option `–-force` with SVN checkout/update command.

This will mark the folder in question as updated and the subfolder files as versioned but will not overwrite any changed you may have in your working copy.

Comment: not sure how to use the '-force' option, can you give me an example please?

Comment: you can use it like this: `svn update --force ./bin/classes/com`

Comment: That gives me the following output:

Skipped 'bin\classes\com'
Summary of conflicts:
Skipped paths: 1

Comment: To resolve the conflict then, use this command: `svn resolved ./bin/classes/com`

Comment: I tried doing that but it tells me that \bin\classes\com is not a working directory. Am I running these commands on the wrong directory? I navigated to my workspace where i checked out the project from my repository and executed the svn resolved in the folder where the bin, src, gen etc folders are.

Comment: Anyways. I deleted the checked out project from the workspace and now imported the trunk and the branch seperately as two checked out projects. Hopefully I wont get the same error in the future.

Comment: OK I hope it would work now. You can close your question by accepting my answer if you think I have helped you in any way... :)

Comment: With all due respect, I couldn't get your solution to work and I had to try an alternative solution. I appreciate your help, but I don't think it would be right to accept it as the final answer.